# Two-Dimensional Array of contacts (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a basic program that allows the use to input and remove up to 10 contacts (a [10][4] array supposed to be filled with First Name, Last Name, Phone #, and age). However when I try to input the 5th contact eclipse gives me an error message. I'd like to know why I'm receiving an error message. (I assume it's something to do with the columns since it's whenever i'm inputting something >4, but i'm not sure what exactly.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Lab2 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            new Lab2 ();
        }

        // This will act as our program switchboard
        public Lab2 (){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[][] personalInfo = new String[10][4];

            System.out.println("Welcome to the contacts database.");
            System.out.println("Please select a number from the options below");
            System.out.println("");

            while(true){
                // Give the user a list of their options
                System.out.println("1: Add a new contact.");
                System.out.println("2: Remove an existing contact.");           
                System.out.println("0: Exit the database.");

                // Get the user input
                int userChoice = input.nextInt();

                switch(userChoice){
                    case 1: 
                        addContact(personalInfo);
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        removeContact(personalInfo);
                        break;              
                    case 0: 
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using the contact database.");
                        System.exit(0);
                }
            }

        }

        private void addContact(String personalInfo[][])
     {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println( " Hello user, please enter your contact info. (I.E. First and Last Names, Phone #, and Age. Max 10 Contacts)");
            String addedContact = input.nextLine(); 


     int j;
        for(int i = 0; i < personalInfo.length; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < personalInfo.length; j++){
           if(personalInfo[i][j] == null)
           {
               personalInfo[i][j] = addedContact; 
           break;
           }


       }
        }
    }



        private void removeContact(String personalInfo[][]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print( " Please enter an existing contact that you would like to remove. ");
    String deleteContact = input.nextLine();
    int i , j;

    for(i = 0; i < personalInfo.length; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < personalInfo.length; j++){
    if(personalInfo[i][j].equals(deleteContact))
    {
        personalInfo[i][j] = null;
    break;
    }


        }
    }

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Give us a hand here. What is the error you are facing ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at Lab2.addContact(Lab2.java:55)
 at Lab2.<init>(Lab2.java:29)
 at Lab2.main(Lab2.java:6)

Comment: I didn't read the code but if it happens when you try to add a 5th contact on a `[10][4]` array... Hmm doesn't it give you clues? You are trying to add a contact to the wrong dimension of the matrix.

Comment: At a fist look, your second for loop should be something like for(j = 0; j < personalInfo[0].length; j++)

Comment: I see I'll attempt to fix it now.

Comment: As far as I can remember, personalInfo.length would give you the number of lines, and personalInfo[i].length would give you the length of the i-th line

Answer (score 0):

Try like this `for(j = 0; j < personalInfo[i].length; j++){`

Answer (score 0):

You're working with *jagged array* (or array of arrays)

```
 String[][] personalInfo = new String[10][4];
```

so in order to itterate it you should use different lengths for dimensions (in general case the 
required length is `personalInfo[i].length`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < personalInfo.length; ++i) // <- outer array
  for (int j = 0; j < personalInfo[i].length; ++j) // <- inner length depends on i
    if (personalInfo[i][j] == null) {
      personalInfo[i][j] = addedContact; 
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me understand it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

```
String[][] personalInfo = new String[10][4];
```

This statement creates a 2dimensional array of Strings, thus creating an array that is capable of holding an array that is capable of holding strings. (in this case 10 arrays that keep 4 strings each)

Now the error:

```
String addedContact = input.nextLine();
```

This line puts the entire line you added in a single string.

Now the loops: 
1. The outer loop loops correctly through the 10 arrays of strings.
2. The inner loop does not loop through the '2nd dimension', that is the actual array which will hold your contact. This loop should be as @Kannan Thangadurai described:

```
    for(j = 0; j < personalInfo[i].length; j++){
      (add relevant code here)
    }
```

The last error you made is more of a bug, and is in the way you read out the user input. You actually only ever put a string in the first array and so your four contacts that you saved will all be under personalinfo[1] then you try to add another contact in the fifth place of the array that does not exist, thus raising your error.

Comment: storing the contact as an array is on a different topic, and could be aproached with: `String[] addThisArray = addedContact.split(' ');`